# db2 merge seems to fail on correct where clause

Tags: sql, merge, db2

I need to merge data from one table to another.

The data is delivered via flat files. That is why I use a load table first before moving it into production.

I add a field `loadtabletime` to the loadtables, so I can tell db2 only to merge one file at a time, even if more than one file is inserted in the load table at one time.

The load table is `loaddlp.reservation_insert`, and the production table is `dlp.reservation`.

This is my query:

```
MERGE INTO DLP.RESERVATION AS E 
USING LOADDLP.RESERVATION_INSERT as et 
   on e.TICKET_SERVER = et.TICKET_SERVER 
  and e.RES_ID = et.RES_ID 
  and et.LOADTABLETIME = '2012-06-09 10:44:17.42236' 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET (foo) = (bar) 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (xyz) VALUES (;akdjf)
```

the primary key for load table is `ticket_server`, `res_id` and `loadtabletime`; for prod table it's `ticket_server` and `res_id`.

This query fails with the following error:

> Could not Update data from the stage to production table RESERVATION.
>   [[23505] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0803N  One or more
>   values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key
>   update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary
>   key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1" constrains
>   table "DLP.RESERVATION" from having duplicate values for the index
>   key.  SQLSTATE=23505

But, when I remove `loadtabletime` from the `where` clause it magically works. Of course, this is not an option as when multiple files are loaded into the load table, you could have pk violations on insert.

When I run:

```
SELECT count(*) 
  from loaddlp.reservation_insert 
 where LOADTABLETIME = '2012-06-09 10:44:17.42236';
```

I get the correct results.

Does anyone has an idea of what's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I solved it.

The key was too add a select query in the 'using' field.

Example:

```
    MERGE INTO DLP.RESERVATION AS e
USING (select * from LOADDLP.RESERVATION_INSERT WHERE LOADTABLETIME = '2012-06-09 10:44:17.42236') as et 
   on e.TICKET_SERVER = et.TICKET_SERVER 
  and e.RES_ID = et.RES_ID  
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET (foo) = (bar) 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (xyz) VALUES (;akdjf)
```